# Making this query build faster

Tags: sql-server, join

I am going to go out on a limb here and ask for help, I have this query that is joining 8 different tables and every time I ran it, it would take forever, I am hoping that someone maybe able to help by helping me simplifying the following query, any help / suggestion would be appreciated, thanks.

```
with CTE as(
select DATEPART(year, a.DATE_RCVD) AS YearRcvd, a.DATE_RCVD, DATEPART(month, a.DATE_RCVD) AS MonthRcvd, a.ITEM_CODE, a.VENDOR_CODE, 
                      d.VENDOR_NAME, a.ITEM_COST_RCVD AS PO_Price, a.ITEM_COST_INV AS AP_Inv_Price, a.QTY_RCVD, b.INVENT_TYPE_IND, a.PO_NUMB, a.PO_LINE_NUMB, 
                      a.DATE_WANTED,
                      CASE WHEN VENDOR_TERMS_PERCENT = 0 THEN 'NET' + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar(4), e.VENDOR_TERMS_DAYS) ELSE CONVERT(varchar(7), 
                      e.VENDOR_TERMS_PERCENT) + '%' + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar(4), e.DISCOUNT_DAYS) + ' ' + 'NET' + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar(4), e.VENDOR_TERMS_DAYS) 
                      END AS TERMS, a.ITEM_COST_RCVD * a.QTY_RCVD AS PO_Value, a.ITEM_COST_INV * a.QTY_RCVD AS AP_InvValue, f.DATE_VENDOR_INV, f.VENDOR_INV_NUMB, 
                      CASE WHEN DATEPART(month, a.DATE_RCVD) < 4 THEN 1 WHEN DATEPART(month, a.DATE_RCVD) >= 4 AND DATEPART(month, a.DATE_RCVD) 
                      < 7 THEN 2 WHEN DATEPART(month, a.DATE_RCVD) >= 7 AND DATEPART(month, a.DATE_RCVD) < 10 THEN 3 ELSE 4 END AS Quarter, 
                      h.FOB_CODE
from podinrh a inner join incinv1 b on a.item_code=b.item_code 
inner join pocpodf c on a.po_numb=c.po_numb and a.po_line_numb=c.po_line_numb 
inner join pocvnms d on a.vendor_code=d.vendor_code 
inner join podpovi e on a.vendor_code=e.vendor_code 
inner join apvhhdr f on a.vendor_code=f.vendor_code
inner join PODPOIH h on a.PO_NUMB=h.PO_NUMB
inner join APVHDTL g on f.VOUCHER_NUMB=g.VOUCHER_NUMB and f.company_code=g.company_code
and a.PO_NUMB=g.PO_NUMB and a.PO_LINE_NUMB=g.PO_LINE_NUMB and a.GRN_NUMB=g.RECEIPT_NUMB and
a.GRN_LINE_NUMB=g.RECEIPT_LINE_NUMB

)
select top 100 * from cte
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask].

Comment: It's impossible to help with this. What are the tables? What indexes? What's the data look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there is a lot that could be done to improve a query's performance -- most often using indexes.

It is hard to help with that without seeing more information about the database.

However, I did see one thing that could be changed...

```
CASE 
  WHEN DATEPART(month, a.DATE_RCVD) < 4 THEN 1 WHEN DATEPART(month, a.DATE_RCVD) >= 4 AND DATEPART(month, a.DATE_RCVD) 
                      < 7 THEN 2 
  WHEN DATEPART(month, a.DATE_RCVD) >= 7 AND DATEPART(month, a.DATE_RCVD) < 10 THEN 3 
     ELSE 4 
END AS Quarter,
```

Should be

```
DATEPART(quarter,a.DATE_RCVD) AS Quarter
```

---

Also, this looks better but probably won't make much of a difference:

```
CASE 
  WHEN VENDOR_TERMS_PERCENT != 0 
  THEN CONVERT(varchar(7), e.VENDOR_TERMS_PERCENT) + '% ' + CONVERT(varchar(4), e.DISCOUNT_DAYS) + ' ' 
  ELSE ''
END + 'NET ' + CONVERT(varchar(4), e.VENDOR_TERMS_DAYS)  AS TERMS,
```